# can you subset while reading in a csv in python

Tags: python, csv, subset

I have daily weather data in csv since 1980, >10GB in size. The column I am interested in date, and I want to be able to have a user select a date so that only the results from that date are returned.

I wonder if it is possible to read in and subset at the same time to save memory and computation

I am relatively new to python and tried:

```
d=pd.read_csv('weather.csv',sep='\t')['Date' == 'yyyymmdd']
```

to no avail.

Is it possible to read in all of the data that is only present for a single day (ei 20011004)?

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** from a `csv` you'll not be able to do so.

**Long answer:** `csv` formats are very handy for humans to read, but it's the worst for machines to operate with. You'll need to parse line by line until you find the lines where the date fits the requested one.

**A possible solution:** You should convert the `csv` into a more amenable format for such operations. My suggestion would be to go with something like hdf5. You can read the whole `csv` with pandas and then save it as a hdf5 file as `d.to_hdf('weather.h5', format='table')`. You can check the pandas hdf documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-hdf5). This should allow you to handle in a more memory and cpu efficient way.

Binary files can implement indexes and sorting in such a way that you don't have to go through all the data to check for those pieces you need. The same ideas apply to databases.

**Addendum:** There are other options for binary formats, like `parquet` (which maybe would be even better you should test) or `feather` (if you want some level of "native" interoperativity with `R`). You might want to check the following [post](https://tech.blue-yonder.com/efficient-dataframe-storage-with-apache-parquet/) for some insights regarding loading/saving times in different formats and their size.